# Google Drive share limit

Tags: google-drive

I have a no-cost 15 GB plan on Google Drive. Someone has shared with me a folder of his, empty, and into which I am to upload 50 GB. He has a sufficiently large plan for the data.

Do I have to buy a larger plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to simply upload 50GB and then forget about it, yes, you will need to upgrade your plan. However, if you can work with the other party to manage the upload in stages, there is a way to make this work without you upgrading your plan.

Quota usage in Google Drive is determined by the owner of the file. Since you will be creating the files, you will be the owner by default - ownership is **not** inherited from the containing folder, so the files will count against your quota. Unfortunately you cannot currently directly transfer ownership of files in Google Drive unless both your account and the other person's account are part of the same G Suite organization, which I assume is not the case here (but if you *are* in the same G Suite org, [here's how to transfer ownership](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892)).

Here's my suggestions for working around this:

Assuming you aren't uploading any single file that is larger than your current available quota, the other party can use Google Drive to create a copy of each file you upload. They would automatically be the owner of the copy, so the copy counts against their quota and not yours. You could then delete your original file to reclaim your quota space before uploading the next file.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be an issue, as the files will not be stored in your account.  You need to have the shared folder open, and upload the files directly into the shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to such problems, requiring third-party software:

- [GoFileDrop](https://www.gofiledrop.com/home) (14 days unlimited trial)
  The other guy can activate it on his Google Account and will then be able
  to send you a link so you can upload directly to his Google Drive account.
- Drive Uploader via
  [G Suite Marketplace](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/drive_uploader/429789668216)
  or their [website](https://driveuploader.com/):

  > Drive Uploader is an easy-to-use application which allows anyone to receive large files to the Google Drive™ account, even from persons who don’t have a Google Drive™ account themselves.